# Failed to execute script "gui" due to unhandled exception: No module named ia

Tags: python, tkinter, excepciones, pygame, pyinstaller

Estoy aprendiendo Python, luego deempaquetar y crear un ejecutable de un proyecto hecho con python,tkinter,pygame usando pyinstaller, trato de abrir el ejecutable creado dentro de la carpeta "dist", pero este me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de mi proyecto y directorios locales es la siguiente, teneiendo en cuenta que el archivo 'gui.py' es el principal o entrada al programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda para solucionar este error, después de muchos intentos no encuentro la solucion